# Can other metal salt compounds besides copper sulfate/zinc sulfate be used to create chlorophyllin? E.g. the magnesium center is replaced

Tags: metal, organometallic-compounds, salt

There has been a lot of research done into sodium copper chlorophyllin. The synthesis is quite simple and can be done at home. It involves extracting the chlorophyll, saponifying the solution, adding the metal salt, and then adding actual sodium.

Most synthesis guides call for copper sulfate, a copper salt. Zinc sulfate can also be used. I was wondering which other copper/zinc 'salts' can be used? I am asking because I was looking at purchasing some OTC zinc/copper supplements, instead of having to spend a lot on a bulk size of FCC copper sulfate, and just using the powder from the capsules/tablets. I see things like copper/zinc bisglycinate, copper gluconate, etc. Copper acetate I could make by just adding vinegar to a copper pot!

It would be most ideal if I could make the substance at home with somewhat easy to find chemicals and a copper bowl. I'm not too wild on burning sulfur to make sulfuric acid at home though :s

Thanks!

Comment: Synthesis of many different types of porphyrins with very many different metals are known and I suppose that the chlorophyllins are not so very different. Many metal centred  phthalocyanins are also known, so searching for  these types of syntheses may be a useful starting point.